# Use the system call select with files

Tags: python, unix, system-calls, nonblocking, single-threaded

I'm trying to write a single threaded non blocking program with the system call [`select`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(Unix)). However, it doesn't work well using file handlers.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import select

while True:
    file_handler = open('filename.txt')
    inputs = [file_handler, sys.stdin]
    try:
        _input, _output, _error = select.select(inputs, [], [])
    except select.error, e:
        print e

    for i in _input:
        txt = i.readline()
        if len(txt) > 0:
            print 'txt:', txt
```

It reaches the print message when there is a new input from stdin, but not when a new line is written to the file. 
It works perfectly fine when using `sockets` instead of files.

Comment: Files don't work that way. The file isn't being monitored for changes. You won't know that the file pointer advanced until you read the file again. You may have luck with `inotify` (assuming this is linux). I haven't used `pyinotify` in years but it was rather horrific and it was better to hack your own solution from its guts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which operating system are you using? Windows or UNIX or MacOS X or what?

Traditionally, the select() call on UNIX-likes systems will return files as "always readable" and "always writable" so trying to use select() for I/O multiplexing will not be useful.

On Windows, select() on files isn't expected to work at all, as it's a feature of the WinSock library.

There are various "file notify" functions and APIs that may be better for your particular case -- Python even has some libraries that abstracts the OS specific code. However, that won't natively interact with sockets very well, so I believe the best way to get a program that both "reacts to input sockets" and "reacts to file changes" without using polling, is to create one or more Python threads.

Comment: On Linux you can use a file descriptor returned by [inotify_init](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) in conjunction with Python-wrapped `select`, `poll`, and `epoll`.  This has been the case since Linux 2.6.13 (released 2005), and should interact with sockets just fine.  The Windows and OSX solutions both look like a train wreck in this department by comparison.

Comment: Adding to the comment, five years late :-) On Windows, you can use WSARecv() and friends and use the OVERLAPPED / GetQueuedCompletionStatus() API on I/O completion ports, which has been in NT since the '90s. It's actually a quite nice API, and I prefer it over all of the POSIX/linux "notify" APIs, so not particularly "trainwreck" at all. But you've got to know to look outside the Berkeley API to find the docs!